# Frattini subgroup of $\operatorname{Hol}(\mathbb Q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\mathbb Q$ be rational number under addtion. Is Frattini subgroup of $\operatorname{Hol}(\mathbb Q)$ trivial where $\operatorname{Hol}(\mathbb Q)=\mathbb Q \rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Q) $?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that the Frattini subgroup is indeed trivial.

Note that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Q) = \mathbb{Q}^{\star}$, acting on $\mathbb{Q}$ by multiplication.

Since $\mathbb{Q}^{\star}$ acts transitively on the nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $\mathbb{Q}$ is minimal normal in $G = \operatorname{Hol}(\mathbb Q)$. This shows that $\mathbb{Q}^{\star}$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$.

Now note that $G$ is isomorphic to the matrix group
$$
H = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\a&b \end{bmatrix} : a \in \mathbb{Q}, b \in \mathbb{Q}^{\star} \right\},
$$
where $\mathbb{Q}^{\star}$ corresponds to $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&b \end{bmatrix} :  b \in \mathbb{Q}^{\star} \right\}$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ corresponds to $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\a&1 \end{bmatrix} :  a \in \mathbb{Q} \right\}$.

Now consider the conjugate subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^{\star}$ by $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\a&1 \end{bmatrix}$, for a fixed $a \ne 0$ (you may take $a=1$, for simplicity). Since
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\a&1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&b \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\a&1 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\-a&1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&b \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\a&1 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\a(b-1)&b \end{bmatrix},
$$
this conjugate is
$$
\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\a(b-1)&b \end{bmatrix} : b \in \mathbb{Q}^{\star} \right\}.
$$
This is again a maximal subgroup of $G$, and intersects $\mathbb{Q}^{\star}$ trivially.

Therefore the Frattini subgroup of $G$ is trivial.

Comment: Just a small comment about where the matrix group comes from. Since $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}) = \operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{Q})$, the holomorph is $\operatorname{AGL}(\mathbb{Q})$. The matrix group here is the usual matrix representation for $\operatorname{AGL}(\mathbb{Q})$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group

Comment: @spin, useful comment, thanks.

Comment: +1 very nice way. When i saw this problem, i guessed that the key might be inside $Aut(Q)$ and see it right now. Can we speak about the nilpotency of Hol(Q) **easily**? Nice to meet you at FB. ;-)

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that, as rightly noted by @spin, this is really a matter of affine groups. With just a little extra effort, but essentially the same argument, one can prove that if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, then the Frattini subgroup of $\operatorname{AGL}(V)$ is trivial.